# Odoo POS Quantity and Price restrict change on particular product

Tags: javascript, python, pos, odoo-15

Hello everyone do any of you know how to restrict changing of price or quantity on specific product in Odoo POS Interface?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have a code yet here because I don't know where to start yet.